# Magento blocks and phtml files not displaying in the right place

Tags: php, magento

I am calling two different phtml files onto the success page.  One is to after the opening body tag to send order data to a third party and the second one is supposed to go before the end body tag to clear the users session.  When I view my page source, the "clear" code is showing at the top of my page directly under the google analytics code, and the "transmit" code does not show at all.  Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
<default>
    <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
    <reference name="after_body_starts">
        <block type="cappscact/track" name="capps_cact" as="capps_cact" template="Capps/Cact.phtml" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="before_body_ends">
        <block type="cappscact/track" name="capps_clear" as="capps_clear" template="Capps/Clear.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

my cact and clear phtml has the following code in them respectively:

```
<?php echo ('<!-- This is a test for Cact -->'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo ('<!-- This is a test for Clear -->'); ?>
```

I expected the first comment for Cact to show under the analytics code and the clear to show near the bottom if not directly above the /body tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your references are right, try to remove the "s" : "after_body_start" "before_body_end" (that's what I see in the Enterprise v1.12)

Comment: You were correct, I checked my page.xml and indeed that is the case. However, after fixing that, clearing xml cache, still a no go. The clear test shows at the top of the page.

Comment: and if i cleared the layout cache, it would have worked.  it has been a long day, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @adrien54 for the answer.
I needed to look into page.xml and gotten the correct block name.  Then clear the layout cache and it would have worked like a charm.